# Javascript Prototype not Working

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Hi I don't know whether this is my mistake in understanding Javascript prototype object ..

Well to be clear I'm new to the Javascript singleton concept and lack clear cut knowledge in that but going through some referral sites I made a sample code for my system but it's giving out some errors which I couldn't find why so I'm asking for your help. My code is:

```
referrelSystem = function(){
//Some code here
}();
```

Prototype function:

```
referrelSystem.prototype.postToFb = function(){
//Some Code here
};
```

I get an error saying prototype is undefined!

Excuse me i thought of this right now

**EDIT**

I have used like this:

```
referrelSystem = function(){
 return{
        login:getSignedIn,
        initTwitter:initTw
    }
};
```

Is this causing an issue?

Comment: What are you returning in your first assignment to `referrelSystem`? Unless you return a Function, it won't have a `prototype` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: Seeing your updated code, the `return` from `referrelSystem` won't work as expected, since return values are discarded when calling `new referrelSystem()`.

Rather than returning an object, set those properties to `this` (the instance of referrelSystem that gets constructed):

```
var referrelSystem = function () {
    // I assume you have other code here

    this.login = getSignedIn;
    this.initTwitter = initTw;
};
```

Comment: sorry () a typo.it's not in the question.

Comment: @Harish, are you sure? I still see a pair of them there ;)

Comment: hmm i just checked once more the protype one was a typo! other was ther thanks for pointing that

Comment: @Harish no worries. There's another problem though, see my updated answer.

Comment: 1 small doubt i called like this                                   var referrelObj = new referrelSystem(); but when i call referrelSystem.postToFb(); i get error that referrelObj.postToFb is not a function

Comment: @Harish, did you add the function to the prototype *before* you called `new referrelSystem()`?

Comment: @Harish, it's really hard to debug unless I can see the full code.

Answer (score 5):

A typical way to define a JavaScript class with prototypes would be:

```
function ReferrelSystem() {
    // this is your constructor
    // use this.foo = bar to assign properties
}

ReferrelSystem.prototype.postToFb = function () {
    // this is a class method
};
```

You might have been confused with the self-executing function syntax (closures). That is used when you would like to have "private" members in your class. Anything you declare in this closure will only be visible within the closure itself:

```
var ReferrelSystem = (function () {
    function doSomething() {
        // this is a "private" function
        // make sure you call it with doSomething.call(this)
        // to be able to access class members
    }

    var cnt; // this is a "private" property

    function RS() {
        // this is your constructor
    }

    RS.prototype.postToFb = function () {
        // this is a class method
    };

    return RS;
})();
```

I would recommend that you study [common module patterns](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) if you're looking into creating a library.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you intend to immediately execute the functions, change them to this:

```
var referrelSystem = function(){
//Some code here
};
```

(+var, -())

Same with the prototype function:

```
referrelSystem.prototype.postToFb = function(){
//Some Code here
};
```

(Here you don't need the var, because you're assigning to something that already exists.)

Answer (score 2):

A function should `return` to work as

> prototype

property.
Take a look at this  [example](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#65) here