# Underscore based iterator prototype not getting value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Using underscore, I iterating a data, and adding in to a function, after i added, i am extending the function using 'prototype' - when i call that prototype i am not getting any value. and the prototype not available for public use at all..

here is my code :

```
var 
data = {
    people : [
        {name:'Caring', state:'Tn', price:'100'},
        {name:'Mo', state:'Ap', price:'200'},
        {name:'af', state:'Jk', price:'33'},
        {name:'adi', state:'Kl', price:'400'},
        {name:'Hu', state:'Ka', price:'600'}
    ]
},

    OrderItem = function(person){
        this.person = person
        getSummary = function(){
          return  person.name
            + ' spent '
            + person.price
            + ' in ' + person.state + '.';
        }

        return {getSummary : getSummary}
    };

    OrderItem.prototype.data = function(){
        return this.person;
    }

    m = _.collect(data.people, function(value, key, list){
        return new OrderItem(value);
    })



_.each(m, function(value){
   // console.log(value.getSummary()); //works fine
    console.log(value.data()); //not working!
})
```

In the _.each method, when i call the value.data I am getting error. how to fix this?

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/5smgC/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Prototype not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953825/javascript-prototype-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

You're only returning the `getSummary` method.
Why not use `this`?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5smgC/2/)

```
OrderItem = function(person){
    this.person = person
    getSummary = function(){
      return  person.name
        + ' spent '
        + person.price
        + ' in ' + person.state + '.';
    }

    return this;
};
```