# Instance does not have access to prototype functions if parent function returns an object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was testing something when I noticed that if you return object from a function, its instance will not have `custom prototype functions`

```js
// This works
function bar(){
  var test = "test";
  return test; 
}

bar.prototype.notify = function(){console.log("Hello Bar");}
var b = new bar();
b.notify()

function bar1(){
  var test = "test";
  return {test: test}; 
}
bar1.prototype.notify = function(){console.log("Hello Bar");}
var b1 = new bar1();
b1.notify()
```

**Note:** [Javascript Prototype not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953825/javascript-prototype-not-working) is a similar post but I'm looking for reason why it is not accessible.

Comment: If value being returned is `primitive`, it will be ignored. If `object` is returned, variable hold returned object..

Comment: there's no reason to use `new ` if you `return` anything other than `this`, and if you don't use use, you can't use protos, and if you can't use protos, then you just have factories, not constructors.

Comment: Well that's because if you don't return an instance, it's not an instance?

Comment: @Bergi but if I return a primitive value, even that is not an instance but now I will have prototype functions.

Comment: @Rajesh: `new` never returns a primitive value. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35702917/1048572) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you make use of the constructor pattern. So the `this` is bound to the new object you create,

```
var b = new bar();
```

That being said, since the constructor's prototype contains a function called `notify`, this function is accessible from every object is created like above. (as a side node keep in mind that it's a convention the first letter of a constructor function, a function that is used only for creating new object using the new operator, to be capital. This way a constructor function is distinguished from the rest functions.)

On the other hand, in the following case:

```
function bar1(){
    var test = "test";
    return {test: test}; 
}
```

the `return` statement overrides the default behavior and it returns a new object.

As it is described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

> When the code new Foo(...) is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1. A new object is created, inheriting from Foo.prototype.
> 2. The constructor function Foo is called with the specified arguments, and with this bound to the newly created object. new Foo is
>      equivalent to new Foo(), i.e. if no argument list is specified, Foo is
>      called without arguments.
> 3. The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't
>      explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used
>      instead. (**Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can
>      choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation
>      process**.)

```js
// This works
function bar(){
  var test = "test";
  return test; 
}

bar.prototype.notify = function(){console.log("Hello Bar");}
var b = new bar();
document.write('b constructor is:'+ b.constructor);
document.write('</br>')

function bar1(){
  var test = "test";
  return {test: test}; 
}

var b1 = new bar1();
document.write('b1 constructor is:'+ b1.constructor);
```